# PHP code for multiple pages with URL like: /index.php#page_name

Tags: php

I used to use this code a while ago and forgot how to implement it.

Essentially it was a way to load different pages into one index.php file. I have the GET version that makes your URLs "/index.php?page=name"

But I am looking for the code that makes your page URLS "/index.php#page_name".

Comment: The server doesn't get the fragment (hash). You have to either use GET parameter or use AJAX to give the fragment (hash) to your php script and load the page this way.

Comment: I dont think that's possible with pure PHP because '#' indicates HTML id's. Maybe you can work with the $_SERVER array and the request url from that

Comment: What Charlotte said. Also possible (in most setups): `/index.php/page_name`, and then read out the url via the `$_SERVER`-array.